# Sum listview decimal

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need a little help with summing deciamls.

I use the code below to show a listview and would like to show a sum of the sale price in the last line in the list view.

```
foreach (Stock c in stock)
{
    string[] subitems = new string[4];
    subitems[0] = c.ID.ToString();
    subitems[1] = c.ItemDescription;
    subitems[2] = "£" + c.PurchasePrice;
    subitems[3] = "£" + c.SalePrice;

    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(subitems);
    SalelistView.Items.Add(listItem);

    ItemNumberTofFnd.Text = "";
}
```

How can i show the total sale price?

I have tried `decimal T += c.SalePrice`, but I'm very unsure as I haven't done this sort of thing before.

Comment: decimal T += c.SalePrice will definitely calculate the total price. don't forget to reset the value of 'T' to 0 before starting the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
decimal total;
foreach (Stock c in stock)
{
    string[] subitems = new string[4];
    subitems[0] = c.ID.ToString();
    subitems[1] = c.ItemDescription;
    subitems[2] = "£" + c.PurchasePrice;
    subitems[3] = "£" + c.SalePrice;

    total += c.SalePrice;

    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(subitems);
    SalelistView.Items.Add(listItem);

    ItemNumberTofFnd.Text = "";
}
SalelistView.Items.Add("Total " + total);
```